# How do I compare an object in python to an integer

Tags: python

This is everything I wrote. I know that Increment.count is equal to 9 as I have put print statements and I have checked everything, but when I set Increment.count equal to 9, it is not ending the game for some reason. The way to end the game is to see if every space on the board is full and no one won yet.

```
import random

board_layout = [
    ' ', ' ', ' ',
    ' ', ' ', ' ',
    ' ', ' ', ' '
]


class Increment:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        Increment.count += 1


def board():
    print(board_layout[0] + '|' + board_layout[1] + '|' + board_layout[2])
    print('-' + '+' + '-' + '+' + '-')
    print(board_layout[3] + '|' + board_layout[4] + '|' + board_layout[5])
    print('-' + '+' + '-' + '+' + '-')
    print(board_layout[6] + '|' + board_layout[7] + '|' + board_layout[8])


def human_turn():
    position = ' '
    position = input('Enter a position from 1-9\n')
    position = int(position) - 1
    board_layout[position] = 'O'
    Increment.count += 1
    board()


def computer_turn():
    while True:
        try:
            position = random.randint(1, 9)
            if is_board_empty(position):
                board_layout[position] = 'X'
                board()
                Increment.count += 1
                break
        except:
            pass


def is_board_empty(position):
    return board_layout[position] == ' '


def is_winner():
    if board_layout[0] != ' ' and board_layout[1] != ' ' and board_layout[2] != ' ' and \
            board_layout[0] == board_layout[1] == board_layout[2]:
        board()
        print(board_layout[0] + ' won!')
        return board_layout[0]
    elif board_layout[3] != ' ' and board_layout[4] != ' ' and board_layout[5] != ' ' and \
            board_layout[3] == board_layout[4] == board_layout[5]:
        board()
        print(board_layout[3] + ' won!')
        return board_layout[3]
    elif board_layout[6] != ' ' and board_layout[7] != ' ' and board_layout[8] != ' ' and \
            board_layout[6] == board_layout[7] == board_layout[8]:
        board()
        print(board_layout[6] + ' won!')
        return board_layout[6]
    elif board_layout[0] != ' ' and board_layout[3] != ' ' and board_layout[6] != ' ' and \
            board_layout[0] == board_layout[3] == board_layout[6]:
        board()
        print(board_layout[0] + ' won!')
        return board_layout[0]
    elif board_layout[1] != ' ' and board_layout[4] != ' ' and board_layout[7] != ' ' and \
            board_layout[1] == board_layout[4] == board_layout[7]:
        board()
        print(board_layout[1] + ' won!')
        return board_layout[1]
    elif board_layout[2] != ' ' and board_layout[5] != ' ' and board_layout[8] != ' ' and \
            board_layout[2] == board_layout[5] == board_layout[8]:
        board()
        print(board_layout[2] + ' won!')
        return board_layout[2]
    elif board_layout[0] != ' ' and board_layout[4] != ' ' and board_layout[8] != ' ' and \
            board_layout[0] == board_layout[4] == board_layout[8]:
        board()
        print(board_layout[0] + ' won!')
        return board_layout[0]
    elif board_layout[2] != ' ' and board_layout[4] != ' ' and board_layout[6] != ' ' and \
            board_layout[2] == board_layout[4] == board_layout[6]:
        board()
        print(board_layout[2] + ' won!')
        return board_layout[2]
    elif Increment.count == 9:
        print('draw')


while is_winner() is None and Increment.count != 9:
    human_turn()
    print('\n')
    computer_turn()
    print('\n')


if Increment.count == 9 and is_winner is None:
    print('draw')
```

Comment: Hello @James, could you please provide a scenario with the inputs that lead towards your issue... Thank you!

Comment: There are nine squares on the board, so both the first turn and the last turn will be the human's.  You only check the while loop after the computer's turn.  Increment.count will only be an even number after the computer's turn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like while the computer is taking its last turn the board is full and the computer goes into a forever loop so we will have to change the computer code to fix it.

replace this

```py
def computer_turn():
    while True:
        try:
            position = random.randint(1, 9)
            if is_board_empty(position):
                board_layout[position] = 'X'
                board()
                Increment.count += 1
                break
        except:
            pass
```

with

```py
def computer_turn():
    while True:
        try:
            if Increment.count == 9:  # If the board is already full
                break
            position = random.randint(1, 9)
            if is_board_empty(position):
                board_layout[position] = 'X'
                board()
                Increment.count += 1
                break
        except:
            pass
```